# On mouse over, hover image have to change

Tags: jquery

Our previous developer, it some logic wrong.

Expected behaviour --> Hover icon have to change as normal icon once mouse out from current navigation. Hover icon have to add on next navigation, once mouse over.

**HTML:**

```
<ul data-desktop-menu>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--category" data-ng-class="{'is-active':isActive()}" data-ng-mouseenter="showSubCategory()" data-ng-mouseleave="showCategory()" data-desktop-menu-item="protect">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons-hd/protect.png" oversrc="images/icons-hd/protect-over.png" alt=""/><span>Protect</span></a>

        <ul data-desktop-submenu="protect">
           <li class="menu-item menu-item--title">
              <a>Protect</a>
           </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item--subcategory">
              <a href="#"><span>Protect 1</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item--subcategory">
             <a href="#"><span>Protect 2</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--category" data-desktop-menu-item="grow">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons-hd/grow.png" oversrc="images/icons-hd/grow-over.png" alt=""/><span>Grow</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--category last" data-desktop-menu-item="assist">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons-hd/assist.png" oversrc="images/icons-hd/assist-over.png" alt=""/><span>Assist Me</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('li.menu-item.menu-item--category').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CSS for this

```
a:hover{background:url('image');background-size:(width,height);}
```

Comment: Hi, Here i need to change hover image value dynamically. CSS is not the solution. Have to control this on JS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
$('li.menu-item.menu-item--category').hover(function() {
   var t=$(this).find('img');  
   var temp=t.attr('src');
   t.attr('src',t.attr('oversrc'));
   t.attr('oversrc',temp);
// $(this).addClass('active');
  }, function() {
 //$(this).removeClass('active');
   var t=$(this).find('img');  
   var temp=t.attr('src');
   t.attr('src',t.attr('oversrc'));
   t.attr('oversrc',temp);
});
```

demo link : http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/msx2vwaj/

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, If i mouse over/out multiple times, this code breaks and not working. Also, we have some <li> with subcategories of <li> tag which works correct earlier. Now, it affects because of this code.  Updated above HTML code with subcategory <li> content. Need solution for <li> without subcategory to change background on hover.